# Ingresar tipos de dato numéricos al string de la sentencia SQL en Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, variables

Tengo la cadena de mi sentencia INSERT con las variables que van a ingresar desde la interfaz gráfica. Pero, en mis tablas se manejan tipos de dato entero y double. Entonces todas mis variables las coloqué como cadena en la sentencia, porque se supone que deben ir así: '"+variable+"', indicando con comillas simples que es una cadena la que ingresa, según la sentencia SQL. Y no me había percatado que tengo los tipos de dato que mencioné anteriormente. Así que, dentro de la sentencia deben ir sin comillas, porque si las dejo así, provocaría un conflicto con lo que tengo definido en la BD. El detalle es que no encuentro la forma de cómo colocar esa variable entera o double de Java dentro de la cadena que forma la sentencia SQL, evitando las comillas simples que definen una valor de tipo cadena. ¿Cómo podría yo colocar estas variables dentro de la cadena de la sentencia?.

```
String IDinsumoP = IDdiaP + IDmesP + IDnombreP + IDinicialP;
String sentencia = "INSERT INTO tbl_stockPersonal VALUES (NULL,'"+IDinsumoP+"','"+cantFinalP+"','"+IDunidadMP+"');";    
try {
    Statement insertar = conexion.crearSentencia();
    return insertar.executeUpdate(sentencia);
}
```

Por ejemplo, tengo este bloque de código. En el String sentencia, cantFinalP es double en la BD, y así la defino en Java; igual IDunidadMP es int. Solo que las coloqué con las comillas simples como dato cadena de la sentencia SQL, cuando no lo son. Si le quito las comillas dobles queda como un valor cadena predeterminado en la sentencia y deja de ser variable de java, además de no cumplir con que debe ser double o int, según el SQL. Si le quito las comillas simples, es un error de sintaxis por tener dos comillas dobles dentro de otras dos en una sola cadena.

Estoy usando MySQL como gestor de BD.

Comment: Pista: ¡sentencias preparadas (`preparedStatements`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar `PreparedStaments`, con eso evitas el uso de las comillas y evitas inyecciones SQL. [Este es un ejemplo](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-prepared-statement-y-su-manejo/):

```
String consulta = "select * from Persona where nombre = ? ";
Connection conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba", "root", "root");
PreparedStatement sentencia= conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
sentencia.setString(1, "pepe");
ResultSet rs = sentencia.executeQuery();
```

Los parametros se reemplazan con (?) signos de interrogación y utilizas funciones como esta para asignar valores:

```
sentencia.setString(1, "pepe");
```